# golang How to get the correct result? floating point arithmetic issues

Tags: go, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

```
testA, testB, testC := big.NewFloat(0), big.NewFloat(0), big.NewFloat(0)
testA.SetPrec(500)
testB.SetPrec(500)
testA.SetString("0.081531021188798896")
testB.SetString("0.9975")
testC.Mul(testA, testB)
testD := testC.Text('f', 500)
fmt.Println("testC", testD)
```

The go result is

0.081327193635826897089025...

while The actual result is

0.08132719363582689876

generated by https://www.calculator.net/big-number-calculator.html

The go result is very close, but not correct

Comment: You are computing with _floats_. If you want exact result do your computation with rational numbers (big.Rat). Computations on floats do not magically become "correct" by raising their precisions to exorbitant values. Your problem ist, that it is impossible to present 0.9975 as a float precisely. See https://0.30000000000000004.com

Comment: Did you intend to do `testC.SetPrec(500)`, too?

Answer (score 0):

```golang
testA, _ := new(big.Rat).SetString("0.081531021188798896")
testB, _ := new(big.Rat).SetString("0.9975")
// testB = new(big.Rat).SetFloat64(0.9975) error
testC := new(big.Rat).Mul(testA, testB)
fmt.Println("testC", testC)
testD := testC.FloatString(500)
fmt.Println("testD", testD)
fmt.Println("trueD", "0.08132719363582689876")
```

https://go.dev/play/p/1c7R2neS2sD